# Specify Colors per 3D Side

Tags: html, css, colors, 3d

I have a bunch of HTML `div` elements displayed in 3D using CSS, and I am wondering if there is a way to apply color (specifcally `background-color`) to each side independantly.
I've tried doing an `element::after { ... }`, but that didn't seem to work. It wouldn't move off of the original element, or it would "flicker" through it...

Sorry, I guess I didn't give much information...

Here is my HTML code (You may be able to tell that I'm building a 3D Rubik's Cube):

```html
<div class="cubeContainer">
    <div class="cube">
        <div class="Ur1c1 blue"></div>
        <div class="Ur1c2 blue"></div>
        <div class="Ur1c3 blue"></div>
        <div class="Ur2c1 blue"></div>
        <div class="Ur2c2 blue"></div>
        <div class="Ur2c3 blue"></div>
        <div class="Ur3c1 blue"></div>
        <div class="Ur3c2 blue"></div>
        <div class="Ur3c3 blue"></div>

        <div class="Fr1c1 orange"></div>
        <div class="Fr1c2 orange"></div>
        <div class="Fr1c3 orange"></div>
        <div class="Fr2c1 orange"></div>
        <div class="Fr2c2 orange"></div>
        <div class="Fr2c3 orange"></div>
        <div class="Fr3c1 orange"></div>
        <div class="Fr3c2 orange"></div>
        <div class="Fr3c3 orange"></div>
        
        <div class="Rr1c1 white"></div>
        <div class="Rr1c2 white"></div>
        <div class="Rr1c3 white"></div>
        <div class="Rr2c1 white"></div>
        <div class="Rr2c2 white"></div>
        <div class="Rr2c3 white"></div>
        <div class="Rr3c1 white"></div>
        <div class="Rr3c2 white"></div>
        <div class="Rr3c3 white"></div>
        
        <div class="Lr1c1 yellow"></div>
        <div class="Lr1c2 yellow"></div>
        <div class="Lr1c3 yellow"></div>
        <div class="Lr2c1 yellow"></div>
        <div class="Lr2c2 yellow"></div>
        <div class="Lr2c3 yellow"></div>
        <div class="Lr3c1 yellow"></div>
        <div class="Lr3c2 yellow"></div>
        <div class="Lr3c3 yellow"></div>
        
        <div class="Dr1c1 green"></div>
        <div class="Dr1c2 green"></div>
        <div class="Dr1c3 green"></div>
        <div class="Dr2c1 green"></div>
        <div class="Dr2c2 green"></div>
        <div class="Dr2c3 green"></div>
        <div class="Dr3c1 green"></div>
        <div class="Dr3c2 green"></div>
        <div class="Dr3c3 green"></div>
        
        <div class="Br1c1 red"></div>
        <div class="Br1c2 red"></div>
        <div class="Br1c3 red"></div>
        <div class="Br2c1 red"></div>
        <div class="Br2c2 red"></div>
        <div class="Br2c3 red"></div>
        <div class="Br3c1 red"></div>
        <div class="Br3c2 red"></div>
        <div class="Br3c3 red"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS (there is a lot):

```css
body {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    justify-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 500px;
}
.cubeContainer {
    perspective: 1000px;
    perspective-origin: center center;
}
.cube {
    position: relative;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform: rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(-25deg);
    animation: rotateAround 10s linear 0s infinite;
    --sticker-size: 60px;
}


@keyframes rotateAround {
    0% {
        transform: rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(-25deg);
    }
    25% {
        transform: rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(calc(-25deg + 90deg));
    }
    50% {
        transform: rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(calc(-25deg + 180deg));
    }
    75% {
        transform: rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(calc(-25deg + 270deg));
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotateX(-15deg) rotateY(calc(-25deg + 360deg));
    }
}


.cube > div {
    width: calc(var(--sticker-size) - 3px);
    height: calc(var(--sticker-size) - 3px);
    border: 2px solid darkslategray;
    background-color: gray;
    position: absolute;
    transition: transform 1s;
}


.cube > div.orange {
    background-color: rgb(255, 102, 0);
}
.cube > div.white {
    background-color: white;
}
.cube > div.blue {
    background-color: royalblue;
}
.cube > div.yellow {
    background-color: yellow;
}
.cube > div.red {
    background-color: red;
}
.cube > div.green {
    background-color: forestgreen;
}


.cube > div.Fr1c1 {
    transform:  translateX(calc(0px - 1.5*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateY(calc(0px - 0.5*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateZ(calc(1.5*var(--sticker-size)));
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.cube > div.Fr1c2 {
    transform:  translateX(calc(0px - 0.5*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateY(calc(0px - 0.5*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateZ(calc(1.5*var(--sticker-size)));
    border-radius: 3px 3px 16px 16px;
}
.cube > div.Fr1c3 {
    transform:  translateX(calc(0px + 0.5*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateY(calc(0px - 0.5*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateZ(calc(1.5*var(--sticker-size)));
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.cube > div.Fr2c1 {
    transform:  translateX(calc(0px - 1.5*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateY(calc(0px + 0.5*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateZ(calc(1.5*var(--sticker-size)));
    border-radius: 3px 16px 16px 3px;
}
.cube > div.Fr2c2 {
    transform:  translateX(calc(0px - 0.5*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateY(calc(0px + 0.5*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateZ(calc(1.5*var(--sticker-size)));
    border-radius: 16px;
}
.cube > div.Fr2c3 {
    transform:  translateX(calc(0px + 0.5*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateY(calc(0px + 0.5*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateZ(calc(1.5*var(--sticker-size)));
    border-radius: 16px 3px 3px 16px;
}
.cube > div.Fr3c1 {
    transform:  translateX(calc(0px - 1.5*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateY(calc(0px + 1.5*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateZ(calc(1.5*var(--sticker-size)));
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.cube > div.Fr3c2 {
    transform:  translateX(calc(0px - 0.5*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateY(calc(0px + 1.5*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateZ(calc(1.5*var(--sticker-size)));
    border-radius: 16px 16px 3px 3px;
}
.cube > div.Fr3c3 {
    transform:  translateX(calc(0px + 0.5*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateY(calc(0px + 1.5*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateZ(calc(1.5*var(--sticker-size)));
    border-radius: 3px;
}




.cube > div.Ur1c1 {
    transform:  rotateX(90deg)
                translateX(calc(0px - 1.5*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateY(calc(0px - 1.0*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateZ(calc(0px + 1.0*var(--sticker-size)));
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.cube > div.Ur1c2 {
    transform:  rotateX(90deg)
                translateX(calc(0px - 0.5*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateY(calc(0px - 1.0*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateZ(calc(0px + 1.0*var(--sticker-size)));
    border-radius: 3px 3px 16px 16px;
}
.cube > div.Ur1c3 {
    transform:  rotateX(90deg)
                translateX(calc(0px + 0.5*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateY(calc(0px - 1.0*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateZ(calc(0px + 1.0*var(--sticker-size)));
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.cube > div.Ur2c1 {
    transform:  rotateX(90deg)
                translateX(calc(0px - 1.5*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateY(calc(0px + 0.0*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateZ(calc(0px + 1.0*var(--sticker-size)));
    border-radius: 3px 16px 16px 3px;
}
.cube > div.Ur2c2 {
    transform:  rotateX(90deg)
                translateX(calc(0px - 0.5*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateY(calc(0px + 0.0*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateZ(calc(0px + 1.0*var(--sticker-size)));
    border-radius: 16px;
}
.cube > div.Ur2c3 {
    transform:  rotateX(90deg)
                translateX(calc(0px + 0.5*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateY(calc(0px + 0.0*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateZ(calc(0px + 1.0*var(--sticker-size)));
    border-radius: 16px 3px 3px 16px;
}
.cube > div.Ur3c1 {
    transform:  rotateX(90deg)
                translateX(calc(0px - 1.5*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateY(calc(0px + 1.0*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateZ(calc(0px + 1.0*var(--sticker-size)));
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.cube > div.Ur3c2 {
    transform:  rotateX(90deg)
                translateX(calc(0px - 0.5*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateY(calc(0px + 1.0*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateZ(calc(0px + 1.0*var(--sticker-size)));
    border-radius: 16px 16px 3px 3px;
}
.cube > div.Ur3c3 {
    transform:  rotateX(90deg)
                translateX(calc(0px + 0.5*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateY(calc(0px + 1.0*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateZ(calc(0px + 1.0*var(--sticker-size)));
    border-radius: 3px;
}



.cube > div.Rr1c1 {
    transform:  rotateY(90deg)
                translateX(calc(0px - 1.0*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateY(calc(0px - 0.5*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateZ(calc(0px + 1.0*var(--sticker-size)));
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.cube > div.Rr1c2 {
    transform:  rotateY(90deg)
                translateX(calc(0px - 0.0*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateY(calc(0px - 0.5*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateZ(calc(0px + 1.0*var(--sticker-size)));
    border-radius: 3px 3px 16px 16px;
}
.cube > div.Rr1c3 {
    transform:  rotateY(90deg)
                translateX(calc(0px + 1.0*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateY(calc(0px - 0.5*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateZ(calc(0px + 1.0*var(--sticker-size)));
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.cube > div.Rr2c1 {
    transform:  rotateY(90deg)
                translateX(calc(0px - 1.0*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateY(calc(0px + 0.5*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateZ(calc(0px + 1.0*var(--sticker-size)));
    border-radius: 3px 16px 16px 3px;
}
.cube > div.Rr2c2 {
    transform:  rotateY(90deg)
                translateX(calc(0px - 0.0*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateY(calc(0px + 0.5*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateZ(calc(0px + 1.0*var(--sticker-size)));
    border-radius: 16px;
}
.cube > div.Rr2c3 {
    transform:  rotateY(90deg)
                translateX(calc(0px + 1.0*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateY(calc(0px + 0.5*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateZ(calc(0px + 1.0*var(--sticker-size)));
    border-radius: 16px 3px 3px 16px;
}
.cube > div.Rr3c1 {
    transform:  rotateY(90deg)
                translateX(calc(0px - 1.0*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateY(calc(0px + 1.5*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateZ(calc(0px + 1.0*var(--sticker-size)));
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.cube > div.Rr3c2 {
    transform:  rotateY(90deg)
                translateX(calc(0px - 0.0*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateY(calc(0px + 1.5*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateZ(calc(0px + 1.0*var(--sticker-size)));
    border-radius: 16px 16px 3px 3px;
}
.cube > div.Rr3c3 {
    transform:  rotateY(90deg)
                translateX(calc(0px + 1.0*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateY(calc(0px + 1.5*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateZ(calc(0px + 1.0*var(--sticker-size)));
    border-radius: 3px;
}



.cube > div.Lr1c1 {
    transform:  rotateY(270deg)
                translateX(calc(0px - 1.0*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateY(calc(0px - 0.5*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateZ(calc(0px + 2.0*var(--sticker-size)));
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.cube > div.Lr1c2 {
    transform:  rotateY(270deg)
                translateX(calc(0px + 0.0*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateY(calc(0px - 0.5*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateZ(calc(0px + 2.0*var(--sticker-size)));
    border-radius: 3px 3px 16px 16px;
}
.cube > div.Lr1c3 {
    transform:  rotateY(270deg)
                translateX(calc(0px + 1.0*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateY(calc(0px - 0.5*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateZ(calc(0px + 2.0*var(--sticker-size)));
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.cube > div.Lr2c1 {
    transform:  rotateY(270deg)
                translateX(calc(0px - 1.0*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateY(calc(0px + 0.5*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateZ(calc(0px + 2.0*var(--sticker-size)));
    border-radius: 3px 16px 16px 3px;
}
.cube > div.Lr2c2 {
    transform:  rotateY(270deg)
                translateX(calc(0px + 0.0*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateY(calc(0px + 0.5*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateZ(calc(0px + 2.0*var(--sticker-size)));
    border-radius: 16px;
}
.cube > div.Lr2c3 {
    transform:  rotateY(270deg)
                translateX(calc(0px + 1.0*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateY(calc(0px + 0.5*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateZ(calc(0px + 2.0*var(--sticker-size)));
    border-radius: 16px 3px 3px 16px;
}
.cube > div.Lr3c1 {
    transform:  rotateY(270deg)
                translateX(calc(0px - 1.0*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateY(calc(0px + 1.5*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateZ(calc(0px + 2.0*var(--sticker-size)));
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.cube > div.Lr3c2 {
    transform:  rotateY(270deg)
                translateX(calc(0px + 0.0*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateY(calc(0px + 1.5*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateZ(calc(0px + 2.0*var(--sticker-size)));
    border-radius: 16px 16px 3px 3px;
}
.cube > div.Lr3c3 {
    transform:  rotateY(270deg)
                translateX(calc(0px + 1.0*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateY(calc(0px + 1.5*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateZ(calc(0px + 2.0*var(--sticker-size)));
    border-radius: 3px;
}




.cube > div.Dr1c1 {
    transform:  rotateX(270deg)
                translateX(calc(0px - 1.5*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateY(calc(0px - 1.0*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateZ(calc(0px + 2.0*var(--sticker-size)));
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.cube > div.Dr1c2 {
    transform:  rotateX(270deg)
                translateX(calc(0px - 0.5*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateY(calc(0px - 1.0*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateZ(calc(0px + 2.0*var(--sticker-size)));
    border-radius: 3px 3px 16px 16px;
}
.cube > div.Dr1c3 {
    transform:  rotateX(270deg)
                translateX(calc(0px + 0.5*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateY(calc(0px - 1.0*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateZ(calc(0px + 2.0*var(--sticker-size)));
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.cube > div.Dr2c1 {
    transform:  rotateX(270deg)
                translateX(calc(0px - 1.5*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateY(calc(0px + 0.0*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateZ(calc(0px + 2.0*var(--sticker-size)));
    border-radius: 3px 16px 16px 3px;
}
.cube > div.Dr2c2 {
    transform:  rotateX(270deg)
                translateX(calc(0px - 0.5*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateY(calc(0px + 0.0*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateZ(calc(0px + 2.0*var(--sticker-size)));
    border-radius: 16px;
}
.cube > div.Dr2c3 {
    transform:  rotateX(270deg)
                translateX(calc(0px + 0.5*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateY(calc(0px + 0.0*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateZ(calc(0px + 2.0*var(--sticker-size)));
    border-radius: 16px 3px 3px 16px;
}
.cube > div.Dr3c1 {
    transform:  rotateX(270deg)
                translateX(calc(0px - 1.5*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateY(calc(0px + 1.0*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateZ(calc(0px + 2.0*var(--sticker-size)));
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.cube > div.Dr3c2 {
    transform:  rotateX(270deg)
                translateX(calc(0px - 0.5*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateY(calc(0px + 1.0*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateZ(calc(0px + 2.0*var(--sticker-size)));
    border-radius: 16px 16px 3px 3px;
}
.cube > div.Dr3c3 {
    transform:  rotateX(270deg)
                translateX(calc(0px + 0.5*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateY(calc(0px + 1.0*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateZ(calc(0px + 2.0*var(--sticker-size)));
    border-radius: 3px;
}




.cube > div.Br1c1 {
    transform:  rotateY(180deg)
                translateX(calc(0px - 0.5*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateY(calc(0px - 0.5*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateZ(calc(0px + 1.5*var(--sticker-size)));
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.cube > div.Br1c2 {
    transform:  rotateY(180deg)
                translateX(calc(0px + 0.5*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateY(calc(0px - 0.5*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateZ(calc(0px + 1.5*var(--sticker-size)));
    border-radius: 3px 3px 16px 16px;
}
.cube > div.Br1c3 {
    transform:  rotateY(180deg)
                translateX(calc(0px + 1.5*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateY(calc(0px - 0.5*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateZ(calc(0px + 1.5*var(--sticker-size)));
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.cube > div.Br2c1 {
    transform:  rotateY(180deg)
                translateX(calc(0px - 0.5*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateY(calc(0px + 0.5*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateZ(calc(0px + 1.5*var(--sticker-size)));
    border-radius: 3px 16px 16px 3px;
}
.cube > div.Br2c2 {
    transform:  rotateY(180deg)
                translateX(calc(0px + 0.5*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateY(calc(0px + 0.5*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateZ(calc(0px + 1.5*var(--sticker-size)));
    border-radius: 16px;
}
.cube > div.Br2c3 {
    transform:  rotateY(180deg)
                translateX(calc(0px + 1.5*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateY(calc(0px + 0.5*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateZ(calc(0px + 1.5*var(--sticker-size)));
    border-radius: 16px 3px 3px 16px;
}
.cube > div.Br3c1 {
    transform:  rotateY(180deg)
                translateX(calc(0px - 0.5*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateY(calc(0px + 1.5*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateZ(calc(0px + 1.5*var(--sticker-size)));
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.cube > div.Br3c2 {
    transform:  rotateY(180deg)
                translateX(calc(0px + 0.5*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateY(calc(0px + 1.5*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateZ(calc(0px + 1.5*var(--sticker-size)));
    border-radius: 16px 16px 3px 3px;
}
.cube > div.Br3c3 {
    transform:  rotateY(180deg)
                translateX(calc(0px + 1.5*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateY(calc(0px + 1.5*var(--sticker-size)))
                translateZ(calc(0px + 1.5*var(--sticker-size)));
    border-radius: 3px;
}




aside.buttons > button {
    width: 40px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

You can also see my code on [Code Pen](https://codepen.io/jacobhornbeck/pen/ZELvYRd).

**I guess people didn't understand my question, so let me rephrase it... I have many `div` elements that I use CSS to display in 3D. In a 3D view, you can have 2 sides to the `div` elements, I want to color these two different sides a different color.**

Is this possible? If so, how simple is it? If not, is there *any* sort of substitute solution?

Comment: Hi, I'm not really understanding what the problem is since it should be straightforward to apply a different color to each div element using CSS. Could you put up a code snippet which shows your HTML structure and CSS?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I guess my question wasn't super detailed... I updated my question with some code, and a more detailed question (the question is at the bottom).

Comment: Ah, thanks. I'm clearer. I seem to recall that the only way I managed to do this in the past was to use pseudo elements as a div doesn't have 2 sides in the way you'd like. How did you try to move the after element?

Answer (score 0):

You could try styling each individual div like this

```
<div style="background-color: #d8bfd8;"></div>
```

Comment: That will just color the entire div.
In 3D the `div` appears to have two sides, I want to be able to color these two sides independantly.

Comment: Your project does seem a bit beyond me. Although you could just set the opposite side to hidden with
`backface-visibility: hidden;` on your `.cube > div {`